# file-error "https://melpa.org/packages/archive-contents" "Bad Request" during emacs 25.2 startup with Prelude initialization

Tags: emacs, emacs-prelude, melpa

New job, new emacs setup. I've used emacs for years but never did much customization. Running CentOS Linux 7.7 and emacs 25.2. I wanted to try the Prelude "starter kit" so I installed it. On emacs starup the Prelude init.el file (~/.emacs.d/init.el) runs and I see: error: Package ‘ag-’ is unavailable.

When I start emacs with debug enabled I see the following back trace:

Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "https://melpa.org/packages/archive-contents" "Bad Request")
signal(file-error ("https://melpa.org/packages/archive-contents" "Bad Request"))
package--download-one-archive(("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") "archive-contents" nil)
package--download-and-read-archives(nil)
package-refresh-contents()
prelude-install-packages()
require(prelude-packages)
.
.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into similar issues on a new Debian install, it looks like there are some setup issues in the default init.el.

Check your init.el against the [https://melpa.org/#/getting-started][1], it currently gives the default melpa link as: "https://melpa.org/packages/" - in my case it was http rather than https.

Then check that M-x package-list-packages works, go through the M-x package-refresh-contents , update cycle. For some reason this took a couple of attempts to work for me.